# My JSON file has %20, %3A characters and when I fetch data in React.js it shows the % characters instead of decoding

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, encoding, character-encoding

I am using React.js and have a questions.JSON file in which I store the data. Now the data in the JSON file is encoded with % characters but when I fetch the data from the file, it shows up with the % characters.

Here's the JSON file example:

```
  {
    "category": "Entertainment%3A%20Video%20Games",
    "type": "multiple",
    "difficulty": "hard",
    "question": "What%20was%20the%20name%20of%20the%20hero%20in%20the%2080s%20animated%20video%20game%20%27Dragon%27s%20Lair%27%3F",
    "correct_answer": "Dirk%20the%20Daring",
    "incorrect_answers": [
    "Arthur",
    "Sir%20Toby%20Belch",
    "Guy%20of%20Gisbourne"
    ]
  },
```

Here's the React code:

```
  const getData = () => {
    fetch('questions.json', {
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json',
  },
  })
    .then(function (response) {
    return response.json()
    })
    .then(function (myJson) {
    setQuestions(myJson)
    })
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, [])

  if (undefined !== questions && questions.length) {
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='question-number'>
        <h2>Question Number</h2>
        <p>{questions[0].category}</p>
        <p>Difficulty: {questions[0].difficulty}</p>
      </div>
      <div className='question'>{questions[0].question}</div>
      <div className='answer-box'>
      <button className='buttons'>{questions[0].correct_answer}</button>
      <button className='buttons'>
          {questions[0].incorrect_answers[0]}
        </button>
        <button className='buttons'>
          {questions[0].incorrect_answers[1]}
        </button>
        <button className='buttons'>
          {questions[0].incorrect_answers[2]}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
} else {
  return <h1>Loading Question</h1>
}
```

I'm quite new to React.js so if I am missing something obvious, please be patient with me.

Comment: You don't seem to be unescaping those characters anywhere, so why _wouldn't_ they show up?

Comment: The code is ok, you answered your question with "Now the data in the JSON file is encoded with % characters", that's the data you got, that's the response you get. You can decode your keys in one of those `.then` like this `decodeURIComponent('Entertainment%3A%20Video%20Games')`

Answer (score 0):

As darklightcodes comment said, you can use `decodeURIComponent`. Here's a simple implementation for that, note that it relies on the objects having the structure in your example:

```
const decode = (obj) => {
  const res = {};
  for (const [key, value] in obj) {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
      // Decode strings directly
      res[key] = decodeURIComponent(value);
    } else {
      // For arrays, decode each string containes
      res[key] = value.map(str => decodeURIComponent(str));
    }
  }
}

const getData = () => {
    fetch('questions.json', {
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json',
  },
  })
    .then(function (response) {
    return response.json()
    })
    .then(function (myJson) {
      // Decode the questions
      setQuestions(myJson.map(question => decode(question)))
    })
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, [])
```

Comment: I tried using this method but now I'm getting "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array" and if I try to remove the '[]' at the end of the use Effect then the site shows a "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined"

Comment: You can use `useEffect(() => { getData() }, [getData])`

Comment: And now I'm getting this error: "The 'getData' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the definition 
of 'getData' in its own useCallback() Hook"